# Passing whole form simply, with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/aH2qC/

Not working. I would like to take what's in the form's action="" and use that as the $.post url. And then I would like to serialize it correct, so it passes everything over just as if I clicked the submit button and got to the /player/admin page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
    $.post(form.attr('action'),
           form.serialize(),
           function(data) {
               alert("Loaded");
           }
      );
```

---

**Update after comment:**

```
$('.followform').submit(function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('rel'));
    var form = $(this);

    $.post(form.attr('action'),
        form.serialize(),
        function(data) {
            alert("Loaded");
        }
    );

    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
});
```

*note - make sure your form selector is correct as well*

```
/* this */
$('.followform') ... 
/* or */
$('[name="followform"]') ...
/* will do */
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer so far. I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/aH2qC/1/ and as you can see when you click the submit, that it is submitting and does not read my 'return false' line, so it takes me to the action="" page anyway. Whats up here?

Comment: I wish to your code still since mine is not working, so why did you include my wrong code in your answer? return false; before $.post is not working ofcourse either.

Comment: what are you still having problems with?

Comment: I still got http://jsfiddle.net/aH2qC/1/ which is your JS solution code. Here I would like to return false, so it only executes the $.post and does not submit to the site, and leaves the current page you are on.

Comment: this works but is not finding the action since it is running on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aH2qC/4/

Comment: When I take this on my site and runs dev tool in chrome I get unexpected token illegal

Answer (score 0):

You need something like below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //v-- Fixed the form selector
    $('.followform').submit(function(e) {
       var form = $(this);
             //   v--- this.action will give you the action URL      
        $.post(this.action, form.serialize(),
           function(data) {
             alert("Loaded");
           });
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('followform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this),
            action = form.attr('action');;

        $.post(action, form.serialize(),
           function(data) {
             alert("Loaded");
           });
    });
});
```